# How to Use DataSource Loop in SoapU Pro

Tags: soapui

I have used Datasource for uploading Excel sheet which has 4 rows data in SoapUI Pro.

on one time running one row will be used for input data. I want to use all 4 rows data so used datasource loop.

After using data source loop and running , its taking 15 rows(4 rows contains data remaining 11 rows are empty).

How to control it to only 4 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Excel document contains these rows even though they are empty. You can circumvent this problem by ignoring empty rows. The Excel DataSource contains the option "Ignore Empty". Check this option and empty rows will be skipped.